# AirBnb iPad app - UITableView over image?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, swift, uiscrollview

AirBnb just came out with their first ever iPad app, it's really slick. There's a `UITableView` over an background image (which is a `UIScrollView` itself). Does anyone have ideas on how to implement it? I assume it's something to do with checking scroll settings? Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about having a scrollview inside a scrollview or how to expand tableView to the full size of the content and turn off scrolling on the tableView? Wish I had an iPad to look at it myself.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how they lay it out: Here's my guess. There's 1. a UIScrollView at the bottom-most layer that's sized to screen edges (top/bottom/leading/trailing). 2. There's UITableView on top. 3. Somehow, the UITableView starts offset towards bottom of screen, as it scrolls, the image in the background resizes. 4. The title "Beautiful loft in Old Montreal" moves & resizses when it encounters the Back button. I'm not sure how to do #3. #4 is cool but not really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly sure the top cell is just blank/clear background...  A variety of ways to do this exist:

- Custom Cell (blank/0 alpha background with a height
- Custom header
- Content Inset of cell 0 being set appropriate;y

Then the transition to the header could be done in the scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method.  I've implemented this before by actually adding a custom subview in the TableView - you can just addSubview: your custom view and when the scrollView hits the correct Offset you fire the animation once...

Or they could have got inventive with the Header delegate method.

Either way - I agree - it's beautifully implemented.